# How to show other .aspx page in LoginView

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, .net, loginview

i have an asp net master page with LoginView in it. If user is anonymous i would like to see the default Register.aspx page in AnonymousTemplate (not as link to it, but the page). Is it possible to do it?
Thanks, Oak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of is using an iframe inside the AnonymousTemplate, but this would lead to an ugly solution. Consider one of the following alternative designs:

- Rework your Register.aspx to Register.ascx and introduce that into
  AnonymousTemplate
- Rework your Register.aspx to a Web form using your
  Master page and redirect to that page in the anonymous case.